# html2canvas not working with pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, html2canvas

I am trying to take a screenshot by using `html2canvas` using `ionicframework`. The html2canvas works in every way except those that i have classes with `:before`. such as

**CSS**

```
.e_amount::before{
    content: "$";
}
```

---

*Before* taking the screen shot it looks like this:
[image]

*After* the html2canvas code:

[image]

---

Noticed the Dollar Sign ($) is not aligned with the 10.00.

I have tried including the style in the head it is still not working. What am i missing?

**JS**

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('card'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        window.canvas2ImagePlugin.saveImageDataToLibrary(
            function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
                var message = {
                    text: "QR Generated",
                    image: "file://"+msg
                };
                window.socialmessage.send(message);
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(err);
            },
            canvas
        );
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="list card" id="card">
    <div class="item item-body">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px;  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;">
            <style>.e_amount::before{content:'$' !important;}</style>
            <div class="col bold">{{"amount" | translate}}</div>
            <div class="col e_amount"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of your code ?

Comment: first of all, do not include style inside body tags, strictly add it into <head>. Secondly , why do you using ::before, maybe for your solution will be much better to include new <span> with tag and than align together

Comment: To get an answer or a comment, you should [write an issue](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/new) to the library author.

Answer (score 0):

reset all margins and paddings for class .e_amount and also set its box-sizing to border-box.